# should python virtual environment should be used with docker images?

Tags: python, python-venv

Should python virtual environment should be used in conjunction with docker images ? Does it even make sense to create virtual environment when using a containerized environment ?

Comment: I vote to close. It all depends on the actual requirements, specifications, environment, etc.
I'd say use the virtual environment both in and outside of the container, this way it's the same consistent technique, less surprises.